# How can i check the time and date using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, datetime

I want to automate my availability timings on my Website using PHP
Here is my availability timings

Like i am available

Mon-Fri 8am-10pm UK TIME and 
Sat-Sun 12-6pm UKT

Is it possible to do that with PHP ?

Any help please..!

Comment: http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/NoCode

Comment: Is there any issue with Question ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your Help,

Comment: @Bilal Are you asking to create something on yourwebsite that will display at which date/time you are available to viewers, and that you can later edit easily?

Comment: Yes it's possible - https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=check+date+and+time+php

Comment: @Webend thanks for your reply let me look around if i can figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Creating a table or some div structure that would dynamically changed depending on your input is relatively simple. The question however would really more depend on what you would like your Control Panel to be to control changes to the availability in your schedule.

The simplest option would be to have a text file that you open edit manually by putting the dates

A more interactive option would be to create a separate page that would allow you to edit the dates (include, delete) that you are available, among other options.

Really it just depends on what you are looking for and how much time you wish to spend on developig it